# What combination of herbs are good to plant in the same window box?

Tags: herbs, container-gardening, companion-planting, window-box

My brother-in-law gave me basil, rosemary and mint.

I planted it in my window box and the basil and rosemary seem to be doing well. The mint dried up right away. I removed most of the dried leaves. Yesterday a couple of new mint leaves came out!

Will my 3 plants cohabitate nicely together in my window box? The window box measures around approximately 24" x 5" x 5". It drains into a shallow trough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, they aren't the best companions. Basil really likes to be watered consistently, while Rosemary prefers to dry out in between waterings. And, as you noticed, mint can survive almost anything and once it recovers will be able to outcompete anything planted with it. If you can move them to separate planters, you could keep the basil in that planter (and add a second basil plant, or parsley, or cilantro, or another herb that likes being kept well-watered) and move the other two to different pots. If this is the only spot you have, you can give it a shot - you may be able to make it work.